# ¿Cúal es el mejor modo de manejar multiples errors en Go?

Tags: go

En Go, errors son valores normales, y es muy común ver algo así:

```
if err := hacerAlgo(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Pero ¿qué hago sí tengo multiples errors?  Por ejemplo, en un método `Close()`:

```
func (x *Algo) Close() (error) {
    if err := x.IOReader.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := io.DB.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

De hecho, en este casó, quiero cerrar el `IOReader` y el `DB`, aunque hay un error con lo primer.  ¿Cuales opciones tengo?

- Retornar solo un error de los errors (el primero o el último)
- Combinar los errors (`retornar err1.Error() + ", " + err2.Error()`)?
- Hacer un tipo de error personalizado que puede guardar los errores completos:  `struct MiError{ errors []error }`

¿Qué es más común o más correcto en estos caso?

Answer (score 1):

En general, "cada error" debiera ser tratado de forma individual, si la sentencia: `x.IOReader.Close()` falla, es correcto retornar solo ese error en particular, ya que ahí se produce el error.

Si quieres cerrar la DB de todas formas, puedes usar `defer` que ejecuta un bloque de codigo antes de que la función retorne, obviamente eso excluye `panic` que termina la ejecución de todo.

Va a depender de la lógica de tu aplicación si es necesario  detener su ejecución (panic) ante una falla relacionada con DBs, que para la mayoria de las aplicaciónes que dependen de una conexion a base de datos debiera ser así:

```
func (x *Algo) Close() error {

    defer func(){
            if err := io.DB.Close(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
    }

    if err := x.IOReader.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Pero si no es asi y tu aplicación está haciendo distintas conexiones y alternando entre ellas y los errores que arroje la funcion Close es manejada en un nivel más alto, podrias realizar lo siguiente:

```
   func (x *Algo) Close() (e1, e2 error) {
    e1 = x.IOReader.Close()
    e2 = io.DB.Close()
    return e1,e2
}
```

Y verificar el resultado en la llamada a Close():

```
e1, e2 := algo.Close()

if e1!=nil{
    log.Printf("Error Closing IOReader!\n")
}
if e2!=nil{
    log.Printf("Error CLosing DB!\n")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré [go-multierror](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror), que proviene la oportunidad de retornar un error que contiene errores multiples. Sí el llamador lo expecta, puede descomprimir el `multierror` para ver los errores individuales.

```
var result error

if err := step1(); err != nil {
    result = multierror.Append(result, err)
}
if err := step2(); err != nil {
    result = multierror.Append(result, err)
}

return result
```